# Finding an iterator corresponding to an object stored in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector v containing objects of type structure say A. Now I need to find the iterator for a particular object stored in this vector. e.g:

```
  struct a
    {
    };
    vector<a> v;
    struct temp;  //initialized
```

Now if I will use

```
find(v.begin(),v.end(), temp);
```

then compiler generates error saying no match for operator `'=='`.

Any workaround for getting an iterator corresponding to an object in a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide either a `bool operator==(const a& lhs, const a& rhs)` equality operator for your class, or pass a comparison functor to `std::find_if`:

```
struct FindHelper
{
  FindHelper(const a& elem) : elem_(elem) {}
  bool operator()(const a& obj) const
  {
  // implement equality logic here using elem_ and obj
  }
  const a& elem_;
};

vector<a> v;
a temp;
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), FindHelper(temp));
```

Alternatively, in c++11 you can use a lambda function instead of the functor.

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),  
                       [&temp](const a& elem) { /* implement logic here */ });
```

Comment: But in find_if how will I pass the object to search for?

Comment: @SegmentationFault You can use a functor (I edited my answer to show an example) or in C++11, a lambda.